# print a triangle figure

Tags: python

I have a mission to write a function called Figure that prints this triangle:
[image]

The code I wrote so far is:

```
def Figure(n):
    spaceNum = n-1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1, n-i+1):
            print(" ", end="")
        for j in range(i,0,-1):
            print(j, end="")
        for j in range(2,i+1):
            print(j, end="")
        print("")
```

This code has a problem because it prints this figure:

```
   1
  212
 32123
4321234
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to include code which works out how many spaces to print inside the triangle.

Comment: What if `n > 9`, what then should be the output?

Comment: Why did you write `for j in range(i,0,-1): print(j, end="")` (the second for-loop inside the outer for loop)? What do you think it prints?